# Logstash -> Elasticsearch Not Mapping Correctly

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

So I recently created an ELK cluster using this site as a template for doing so.[ELK Cluster Setup](http://everythingshouldbevirtual.com/highly-available-elk-elasticsearch-logstash-kibana-setup)

I am running into a problem where the json template on the Logstash processing node isn't being used on the actual Elasticsearch data nodes. I can see the mapping has been created in HQ but another one was created that is using some dynamically created mappings. The mapping that is done right is called "Sourcefire" on the data nodes, but it also created one called "sourcfire" that isn't right.

I can't figure this out and I'm learning this stuff so any help is appreciated. See below for code snippets.

Logstash.conf

```
input {
    tcp {
        port => 5170
        type => "sourcefire"
    }
}

filter {

    mutate{
        split => ["message", "|"]
        add_field => {
            "event" => "%{message[5]}"
            "eventSource" => "%{message[1]}"
        }
    }

    kv {
        include_keys => ["dhost", "dst", "dpt", "shost", "src", "spt", "rt"]
    }

    mutate {
        rename => [ "dhost", "destinationHost" ]
        rename => [ "dst", "destinationAddress" ]
        rename => [ "dpt", "destinationPort" ]
        rename => [ "shost", "sourceHost" ]
        rename => [ "src", "sourceAddress" ]
        rename => [ "spt", "sourcePort" ]
    }

    date {
        match => ["rt","UNIX_MS"]
        target => "eventDate"
    }

    geoip {
        add_tag => [ "sourceGeo" ]
        source => "src"
        database => "/opt/logstash/vendor/geoip/GeoLiteCity.dat"
    }

    geoip {
        add_tag => [ "destinationGeo" ]
        source => "src"
        database => "/opt/logstash/vendor/geoip/GeoLiteCity.dat"
    }
}

output {
    if [type] == "sourcefire" {
        elasticsearch {
            cluster => "XXX-cluster"
            flush_size => 1
            manage_template => true
            template => "/opt/logstash/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-sourcefire.json"
        }
    }
}
```

Elasticsearch json template

```
{
    "template": "logstash-*",
    "settings": {
        "index.refresh_interval": "5s"
    },
    "mappings": {
        "Sourcefire": {
            "_all": {
                "enabled": true
            },
            "properties": {
                "@timestamp": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "basicDateTimeNoMillis"
                },
                "@version": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "geoip": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "dynamic": true,
                    "path": "full",
                    "properties": {
                        "location": {
                            "type": "geo_point"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "event": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "eventDate": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "basicDateTimeNoMillis"
                },
                "destinationAddress": {
                    "type": "ip"
                },
                "destinationHost": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "destinationPort": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "sourceAddress": {
                    "type": "ip"
                },
                "sourceHost": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "sourcePort": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the template_overwrite property of the elasticsearch output. However, it is not guaranteed to always work properly, especially if you have multiple logstash instances that work simultaneously. Also, depending on your elasticsearch mapping configuration settings, specifically dynamic mapping and default settings (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-dynamic-mapping.html), you might get different results than you expected.

From my experience, I found it's best to manually control the index mappings in elasticsearch (using tools like fiddler, or elasticsearch-head management site). This is because i experienced various unexpected results when multiple logstash instances overwrote the mappings together, disabling special elasticsearch fields that i set up (like _ttl).

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the stored template and it should recreate it back:
Example, if your template name is `logstash`:

`curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/_template/logstash`

Also, if you are writing to the same index, you cannot change the mapping. You need to recreate the index (make sure to stop the logstash first to prevent any inflight).